# Rubymine 4 on OS X Lion: how to access bundled database support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, plugins, rubymine

This must be obvious, but I can't find any way to access the bundled database support in my brand-new Rubymine 4.0.2, on OSX Lion. Looking in Preferences|Plugins, Database Support is checked and marked as "Bundled", which presumably means it is installed. Also, Rails projects with new database requirements lead to prompts to install appropriate JDBC connectors (i.e. mysql, sqlite, etc) which install fine. Puzzled.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Currently I use sequelpro or sqlite-manager to manipulate databases while doing Rails development. It would be handy to use a DB tool integrated in the IDE, similar to Visual Studio's database integration. That's what this plugin is supposed to deliver.

Comment: Yes, but I still like to see the actual database tables. Also, I often browse external databases. Is this unusual? Don't most Rails programmers look at the database? In either case, this is functionality that is supposed to come with Rubymine - I just can't see how to access it.

Comment: Well, I personally don't use gui tools to look at databases. CLI is enough. Good luck with this :)

Comment: Perhaps someone else who does use IDEs has a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I missed it, though it's certainly not obvious: to access the DB UI, select View | Tool Windows | Data Sources. Works okay in a pinch, but not really a replacement for a good DB tool - many free tools are much better.